Improper Integral of a complex-valued function with a singularity on the real line
As part of an example in the Complex Analysis book by Bak and Newman, the authors use a nice trick which is:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = 
Im \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx =
Im \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix} -1}{x}dx
$$
With the last transition done to avoid a function with a pole at zero, since for $f(z) = \frac{e^{ix} -1}{x}$ there is a removable singularity at $z=0$.
The authors then use standard contour integration to calculate the integral, making use of the fact that the contour integral is zero for f on the upper half circle.
My questions are just to make sure I fully understand the reasoning behind the steps involving removable singularities:
Question #1 - How do we formaly justify a (complex valued, improper) integral with a removable singularity on the path of integration (e.g on the real line in this case)?
In this case I assume it is simply that we can replace the function with another one which is analytic on the real line (e.g. replace $f(0)$ with $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$) which is guaranteed to exist at a removable singularity and then since these functions differ at a single point their integrals are equal?
Question #2 - How do we formally justify that the contour integral for f(z) on the upper half circle (of radius r) is zero when it has a singularity on the actual contour itself in this case (at zero)?
Since its removable we simply alter the function at that point to make it analytic on the contour and then since its also analytic inside we get that the contour integral is zero by Cauchy. But then we can argue similarly to above point that the integrals are identical for the original and the altered function because they differ at a single point only?
Question #3 - How do we formally justify that the contour integral on a (simple) closed contour around a (single) removable singularity is equal to zero?
Similarly, we just replace the function with one that is analytic at the removable singularity, and then we get a function that is analytic on and inside the contour and therefore can use Cauchy theorems to argue the integral is worth zero, but then the functions are identical on the contour itself therefore the integrals are equal. is that right?
